# How do you customize the search results description for DotNetNuke?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm using DotNetNuke 6's included search provider, and I'd like to customize the descriptions for pages that show up under search results.

Instead of a smattering of content, I'd like to use something like the page's meta description, as that looks much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages themselves aren't "indexed" using the default search provider in the community edition of DotNetNuke. The Modules themselves are indexed, so the descriptions and content that is indexed is up to the module developer. Only modules that implement the ISearchable interface are indexed.

The Professional Edition of DNN has search spider/results functionality built in which provides a better search result.

Comment: So in the dnn.searchResult.js, line 112: markup += '<div class="dnnSearchResultItem-Description">' + data.Snippet. + '</div>'; returns page header javascript comments in the page results. UGLY. Beside removing that code, is there a way for DNN to not return page header js comments?